# $exceptionHandler to show error message on page

Tags: angularjs

What is the best solution to display error message on some element on HTML page?

Currently I have overriden `$exceptionHandler` to store error message to `$rootScope.errorMessage` and then on HTML page I'm using `ng-show` on `div` to show the content of the variable.

My div is located at top of the `ng-view` so it's not included to partials.

When error occurs the `div` is updated correctly but how can I reset it when user does some action, example ng-click in some partial.

I'm able to reset error message when navigating from page to another.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is probably quite a number of ways of doing this. You could define a $on message to listen for and then $emit 'said message' throughout code. Alternatively, you could play with listening for clicks on the body element, presuming nothing down the stack stops propagating the events.

For me it kinda depends on how big your app is.

hope this helps